# Getting the class of the element that fired an event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

is there anyway to get the class when click event is fired. My code as below, it only work for id but not class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id + " and " + event.target.class);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <a href="#" id="kana1" class="konbo">click me 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="kana2" class="kinta">click me 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```

jsfiddle code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fv3Ca/1/)

Comment: Class is a reserved work in ECMAScript, so the class attribute is mapped to the `className` DOM property. Use `event.target.className`.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
       alert(event.target.id+" and "+$(event.target).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 137):

This will contain the full class (which may be multiple space separated classes, if the element has more than one class). In your code it will contain either "konbo" or "kinta":

```
event.target.className
```

You can use jQuery to check for classes by name:

```
$(event.target).hasClass('konbo');
```

and to add or remove them with [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 29):

You will get all the class in below array

```
event.target.classList
```

Comment: I find this answer more helpful compared to @broesch's. It has less dependencies and seems more natural at this point.

Answer (score 6):

A variant on Vishesh answer, which instead returns a Boolean:

```
event.target.classList.contains(className)
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
    var myId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(myClass + " " + myId);
  });
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" id="kana1" class="konbo">click me 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="kana2" class="kinta">click me 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```

This works for me. There is no event.target.class function in jQuery.

Comment: for some reason i have to use the event, anyway thanks for the answer. broesch has answered what i need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery 1.7:

```
alert($(this).prop("class"));
```

or:

```
alert($(event.target).prop("class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful as `target` might not work with all browsers, it works well with Chrome, but I reckon Firefox (or IE/Edge, can't remember) is a bit different and uses srcElement. I usually do something like

```
var t = ev.srcElement || ev.target;
```

thus leading to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(ev) {
        // get target depending on what API's in use
        var t = ev.srcElement || ev.target;

        alert(t.id+" and "+$(t).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

Thx for the nice answers!

Comment: `target` works with Firefox, IE/Edge would need `srcElement`

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(e.target).hasClass('active')
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.