# Only one jquery function for different audio files on hover

Tags: jquery, audio, hover, dry

I am having an audio which starts playing when hovering a text, which looks like this:

```js
$(".textOne p").hover(function() {

  $(".audioOne")[0].play();
  $(".audioOne")[0].volume = 0;
  $(".audioOne").animate({
    volume: 1
  }, 800);

}, function() {

  $(".audioOne").animate({
    volume: 0
  }, 800);

  timeOutAudio = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".audioOne")[0].pause();
    $(".audioOne")[0].currentTime = 0;
  }, 800);

});

//REPEATING FOR SECOND AUDIOFILE

$(".textTwo p").hover(function() {

  $(".audioTwo")[0].play();
  $(".audioTwo")[0].volume = 0;
  $(".audioTwo").animate({
    volume: 1
  }, 800);

}, function() {

  $(".audioTwo").animate({
    volume: 0
  }, 800);

  timeOutAudio = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".audioTwo")[0].pause();
    $(".audioTwo")[0].currentTime = 0;
  }, 800);

});
```

But I would like to avoid that I have to duplicate the functioning for each audio file and text. Does someone know what would be the best way to not repeat yourself here?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to use **closures**:

```
$('.textOne p').hover(onHoverStartPlayAudio('.audioOne'), onHoverEndPauseAudio('.audioOne')) ;
$('.textTwo p').hover(onHoverStartPlayAudio('.audioTwo'), onHoverEndPauseAudio('.audioTwo')));
function onHoverStartPlayAudio(audioName) {
    return function (event) {
        $(audioName).on('timeupdate', function() {
            $(event.target).css({
                "background-size": this.currentTime / this.duration * 100 + '%' + '100%',
            });
        });

        $(audioName)[0].play();
        $(audioName)[0].volume = 0;
        $(audioName).animate({ volume: 1 }, 800);
    } 
}

function onHoverEndPauseAudio(audioName){
    return function() {
        $(audioName).animate({ volume: 0 }, 800);
        timeOutAudio = setTimeout(function() {
            $(audioName)[0].pause();
            $(audioName)[0].currentTime = 0; 
         }, 800);
    } 
}
```

Then in the inner function you can use `audioName` which will contain `.audioOne` or `.audioTwo` depending on which button was hovered.

Let me know if the explanation is clear enough.

Hope it helps

## **Edit:**

I've added the code from the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fczb7t8v/3/) provided, the CSS of the hovered element will change on `timeupdate`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then both audio files would be played, right? Or do I read it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot the difference before, I will update my response

Comment: Thanks for updating. Ive tried it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fczb7t8v/3/
But its not working. Guess I made something wrong

Comment: Your code looks pretty good, the only thing is that you should only return one Function from the closure.. That's it one closure for `onHoverStartPlayAudio` and the other one is for `onHoverEndPauseAudio`.

Comment: Works perfectly ! Can I ask you one more thing? do you see the css function in the fiddle I sent in my previous comment? What would be the best way to only select the class for the css which I hover? like for example: hovering $(".textOne p") change $(".textOne p").css

Comment: If you want to change the CSS of the hovered element [This answer will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39297917/8371135), if you want to change the CSS of all the items that have the same class of the hovered element [This answer will be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026078/8371135).